# Thread synchronization inside if/else block in CUDA

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gaussian, thread-synchronization

I want to implement Gaussian elimination in CUDA. But I have problem with thread synchronization inside if/else.

Here is my simple code:

```
__device__ bool zr(float val) {
    const float zeroEpsilon = 1e-12f;
    return fabs(val) < zeroEpsilon;
}

__global__ void gauss(float* data, unsigned int size, bool* success) {
    //unsigned int len = size * (size + 1);
    extern  __shared__ float matrix[];
    __shared__ bool succ;
    __shared__ float div;
    unsigned int ridx = threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int cidx = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int idx = (size + 1) * ridx  + cidx;
    matrix[idx] = data[idx];
    if (idx == 0)
        succ = true;
    __syncthreads();
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
        if (ridx == row) {
            if (cidx == row) {
                div = matrix[idx];
                if (zr(div)) {
                    succ = false;
                    div = 1.0;
                }
            }
            __syncthreads();
            matrix[idx] = matrix[idx] / div;
            __syncthreads();
        }
        else {
            __syncthreads();
            __syncthreads();
        }
        if (!succ)
            break;
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (idx == 0)
        *success = succ;
    data[idx] = matrix[idx];
    __syncthreads();
}
```

It works this way:

1. Copy matrix into shared memory.
2. Iterate over rows.
3. Divide row by value on it's diagonal.

The problem is inside if/else block inside for loop - deadlock:

```
==Ocelot== PTX Emulator failed to run kernel "_Z5gaussPfjPb" with exception: 
==Ocelot== [PC 30] [thread 0] [cta 0] bar.sync 0 - barrier deadlock:
==Ocelot== context at: [PC: 59] gauss.cu:57:1 11111111111111111111
==Ocelot== context at: [PC: 50] gauss.cu:54:1 11111111111111111111
==Ocelot== context at: [PC: 33] gauss.cu:40:1 00000000000000011111
==Ocelot== context at: [PC: 30] gauss.cu:51:1 11111111111111100000
```

I hava no idea why is that. When I remove synchronization from if/else block it's works. Can someone explain me that?

Comment: I'm using GPU Ocelot to emulate CUDA env.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CUDA: \_\_syncthreads() inside if statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519573/cuda-syncthreads-inside-if-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__syncthreads()` is doing this.

When a `thread` reaches `__syncthreads` as an instruction it will block/stall, when that happens the `warp` (32 threads) will also block, it will block until all `threads` in the same `block of threads` have reached that statement.

However, if one warp or one thread in the same `block of threads` does not reach the same `__syncthreads` statement it will deadlock as at least one `thread` is waiting for all the other `threads` to reach the same statement, if if does not happen you will get a **deadlock**.

What you are now doing is excluding at least one `threads` from participating in the `__syncthreads` event, by placing a `__syncthreads` inside a if statement not all threads will reach. Thus, **deadlock**.

Comment: I thought that `__syncthreads()` locks on some abstract object (semaphore or sth). But as I see it locks on statement. Strange for me.

Comment: I would guess it is something similar to the ballot function, abstract how it could work `if(__popc(ballot()) != blockDim.x) { block();} else {notify();}`

Answer (score 2):

`__syncthreads()` waits until all threads of one threadblock have reached this point and finished their calculations. Because of your if/else-condition some threads are waiting in the else-loop and some in the if-loop and they waiting for each other. But the threads in the if-loop never reach the else-loop.