# CUDA threads appear to be out of sync

Tags: cuda

I have an issue where it appears that a single thread is trailing behind the rest, even though i'm using syncthreads. The following extract is taken from a large program, where I've cut out as much as I can yet it still reproduces my problem. What I find is that upon running this code the test4 variable does not return the same value for all threads. My understanding is that using the TEST_FLAG variable it should lead all threads into the `if (TEST_FLAG == 2)` condition and therefore every element in the array test4 should return a value of 43. However what I find is that all elements return 43, except thread 0 which returns 0. It appears as if the threads are not all getting to the same syncthreads. I've performed numerous tests and I've found that removing more of the code, such as the `for (l=0; l<1; ++l)` loop resolves the issue, but I do not understand why. Any help as to why my threads are not all returning the same value would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.compiler
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.cumath as cumath
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

gpu_code=SourceModule("""
    __global__ void test_sync(double *test4, double *test5)
    {
        __shared__ double rad_loc[2], boundary[2], boundary_limb_edge[2];
        __shared__ int TEST_FLAG;
        int l;


        if (blockIdx.x != 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(threadIdx.x == 0)
        {
            TEST_FLAG = 2;
            boundary[0] = 1;
        }

        test4[threadIdx.x] = 0;
        test5[threadIdx.x] = 0;

        if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        {
            rad_loc[0] = 0.0;
        }
        __syncthreads();

        for (l=0; l<1; ++l)
        {
            __syncthreads();
            if (rad_loc[0] > 0.0)
            {
                test5[threadIdx.x] += 1;

                if ((int)boundary[0] == -1)
                {
                    __syncthreads();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (threadIdx.x == 0)
                {
                    boundary_limb_edge[0] = 0.0;
                }
            }
            __syncthreads();

            if (TEST_FLAG == 2)
            {
                test4[threadIdx.x] = 43;
                __syncthreads();

                TEST_FLAG = 99;
            }
            __syncthreads();

            return;
        }
        return;
    }

    """)


test_sync = gpu_code.get_function("test_sync")

DATA_ROWS=[100,100]

blockshape_data_mags    = (int(64),1, 1)
gridshape_data_mags     = (int(sum(DATA_ROWS)), 1)

test4 = np.zeros([1*blockshape_data_mags[0]], np.float64)
test5 = np.zeros([1*blockshape_data_mags[0]], np.float64)

test_sync(drv.InOut(test4), drv.InOut(test5), block=blockshape_data_mags, grid=gridshape_data_mags)

print test4
print test5
```

Comment: __synchthreads() might not have user-defined behavior inside conditional statements, even if all threads are in the same block of code. An example was given by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519573/cuda-syncthreads-inside-if-statements

Comment: I was under the impression that it would only be problematic if all threads did not follow the same branch, as in the example you linked. Where as in my example all threads follow the same path, so I wouldn't expect any issues with the syncthreads.
From [B.6. Synchronization Functions of the CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf)
__syncthreads() is allowed in conditional code but only if the conditional evaluates
identically across the entire thread block, otherwise the code execution is likely to hang
or produce unintended side effects

Comment: Could you please provide a complete reproducer, rather than just the kernel?  I have no idea what your launch configuration is, and other details, and I'd rather not guess.  This is definitely wierd code.  For example, you are using the value of `boundary[0]` in a conditional before you are initializing it.   Note that SO expects:  "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: I am running this using pycuda (version 2011,2,2) in python 2.7.3 on a Tesla C2075 card. I'm running it using a block of (64,1,1), grid (200,0,0). But they don't have any affect on the outcome, test4 and 5 are arrays equal in length to the number of threads. I've replaced the above code with the entire python script, including the amendment of the lack of boundary[0] initialization I must have accidentally removed from the original. I hope this information helps. If you need more information let me know.

Comment: I believe I have replicated the issue (although I'm not using python) and will be studying it further.  In the meantime, I believe you might be able to work around the problem if you can tell pyCUDA to pass `-G` to the `nvcc` compiler.  I'm not sure how to do that but I think it should be easy to find the answer somewhere.  Your code may run slower with the `-G` switch.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I've included the -G flag into the python code and it runs as expected, with all threads returning the same value. From my understanding of the flag am I correct in saying the -G flag on it's own removes any compiler optimization?

Comment: It removes almost all optimizations from the device (kernel) code.

Comment: Robert: Have you made any progress with your investigation into this odd behavior? I have found a temporary fix by using more syncthreads, but I am not convinced it is completely reliable. Although `-G` does make it run as expected, it is significantly slower and unfortunately time is a key factor in this code.

Comment: @Robert Crovella Did you ever get any further with this issue? I know it has been nearly two years since I originally presented this question, however I am running into what I suspect could be a similar issue, now that I have migrated onto a new system using Maxwell architecture. My production code runs fine on a Tesla C2075, K40c, but not on a Titan X. If you didn't get any further with this, I'll try to create a new example case, and post a new question detailing the unusual behavior it is now presenting on the Maxwell device.

Comment: After conferring with colleagues, the code was deemed to be illegal, containing a race condition. You can verify this yourself by running a standalone executable version of your app with `cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck ...` using recent CUDA toolchains. If you continue to have trouble with other codes, my suggestion would be to work with the codes until any race conditions reported by `cuda-memcheck` are eliminated. At that point, if there is still difficulty, feel free to post a new question. (Of course, you're welcome to post any sort of question at any time. The above is just my suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

As Yuuta mentioned, `__syncthreads()` behavior is not defined in conditional statements. Thus having it there may/may not work as expected. You may want to re-write your code to avoid getting `__syncthreads()` into your if conditions.

You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519573/cuda-syncthreads-inside-if-statements) and [this paper](http://www.stuffedcow.net/files/gpuarch-ispass2010.pdf) for more information on `__syncthreads()`.

It is also important to notice that it is a block level barrier. You can't synchronize different blocks using `__syncthreads()`. Blocks must be synchronized by kernel calls.

Comment: As I mentioned in my response to Yuuta, the CUDA programming guide states (section B.6.).
"`__syncthreads()` is allowed in conditional code but only if the conditional evaluates identically across the entire thread block, otherwise the code execution is likely to hang or produce unintended side effects."
The example code above does evaluate identically across the block, so there is no thread divergence. This is also re-iterated in the paper you referred me to, which focuses on situations of thread divergence. Unless I misunderstood it.

Comment: I have generated a simpler test case that reproduces the same issue and has no instances of `__syncthreads()` within a conditional, so I agree that this is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the statement TEST_FLAG=99. For one of the threads, it is executed before thread 0 enters the conditional block, and gives you undefined behavior. If I comment out TEST_FLAG=99, the code runs as expected.

Comment: I realize that without `TEST_FLAG=99` the threads would all return the same value, that is why I have a test flag there. It is used to identify that for some reason not all threads appear to be synchronized on the line just above the `TEST_FLAG=99` which should have the affect of all threads going inside the `if (TEST_FLAG == 2)` conditional statement and writting a number to test4 then syncing, before the `TEST_FLAG` shared variable is changed.

Comment: I agree that all threads should go inside if(TESTFLAG==2)if (TEST_FLAG == 2) block. However, when I add the following print statement before this block: `printf("testflag %u %u\n", threadIdx.x, TEST_FLAG);`, it shows that thread 0 has TEST_FLAG set to 99, while all the others have it set to 2, so ultimately thread 0 does not enter the block.